# how to disable animation when rendering a page?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-animations

It is necessary that when the button is pressed, there is an animation of the appearance and hiding of the text. I wrote the following code, but when the page renders, the text hide animation is triggered.
Can I turn off the animation that fires when the page is rendered? Sample code below.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  let [vision, setVision] = useState(true);
  let hangler = () => {
    setVision(!vision);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 className={vision ? "Text hidden" : "Text shown"}>Hello World</h1>
      <button onClick={hangler}>click</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Css:

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
.Text {
  color: blue;
}
.hidden {
  animation: fadeOut ease 1.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.shown {
  animation: fadeIn ease 1.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

This code is at this [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-pine-6zfnx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your classes are inverted, it should be `vision ? "Text shown" : "Text hidden"`.

This will still animate the header to fade in. If it's ok then you are done.

However, if you don't want the initial animation. You can set `animation-duration: 0s;` to short-circuit it and remove the property after the load but this is not elegant.

For something that simple I would use transitions instead.

```
.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 1.5s, visibility 1.5s;
}

.shown {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: opacity 1.5s, visibility 1.5s;
}
```